Using makereal in tldraw in jupyterlab
I am in China and I am using university computing cluster remotely in login node to access jupyter lab and run python with the following code:
from tldraw import MakeReal
from api_key import api_key

m = MakeReal(width=1002, height = 500, api_key = api_key)
m

The above created a white board where I can draw as I like. I drew a linear regression line and clicked Make Real button. I was returned that OpenAI request takes about 5 seconds. But the matplot code never appears automatically. Is there any step I am missing or just because I am in China and ChatGPT is blocked?
